# convert protected DVD-files to unprotected files

Tags: gratis, video, optical-media, mp4

I want to convert my DVDs to MP4-files. I know a Software that can convert unprotected files, but I have many DVDs which are protected. Does anyone know a good Freeware?

I already tried HandBrake and many others but None of them works.

Comment: On what Os should that software run?

Comment: Handbrake should work, all it needs is a plugin to read the protected files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [MakeMKV](http://www.makemkv.com/) - currently free while in Beta, and likely will be for quite some time.

You can subsequently use Handbrake to compress the resulting file, if you so wish.